# Proof $7 | (100m + n) \Rightarrow 7 | (m + 4n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My task is to prove the above, with $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$

Here is what I have:

$7 | (100m + n) \iff (100m +n) \mod 7 = 0$

$\iff (100m \mod 7 + n \mod 7) \mod 7 = 0 $

$\iff (2m +n) \mod 7 = 0$

That is where I am stuck.

Comment: Multiply by 4, and you get $8m + 4n$, and $8 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$100m+n=7k$$
$$2m+n=7k-(7\times14)m$$
$$4(2m+n)=4(7k-(7\times14)m)$$
$$m+4n=4(7k-7\times14m)-7m=7\ell$$

Answer (score 1):

More generally,

> $7 \mid (100m + n) \iff 7 \mid (m + 4n)$

Indeed, let $a=100m + n$ and $b=m + 4n$. Then
$$
a-2b = 98m -7n \equiv 0 \bmod 7
$$
Therefore, $a \equiv 2b \bmod 7$. The result follows because $b \equiv 0 \bmod 7$ iff $2b \equiv 0 \bmod 7$.